# Does enabling core dump require -g for gcc?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, coredump

In order to enable creating core dump from a running program when it exits abnormally, is it required to specify the debug option -g for gcc during compilation?

Answer (score 4):

No, your program will core dump fine. It will lack debug symbols however, which means that it will be pretty difficult to match up the core dump with the original code.

Comment: Thanks. without -g, is the core dump  useless for debugging? What can the core dump be used for then?

Comment: You can still extract some information from the core dump but you wouldn't be able to match anything in the core dump up with any symbol names in your source files.

Answer (score 3):

No, that are two different things. However enabling debug information might be a good idea since it makes the core dump more useful.

If you have the situation that the executable is shipped to customer or for some other reason don't want to ship the debug information the thing you would want to do is still to build with the -g flag and then strip the debug information from the executable and ship that.

This way you would end up with two executables, one without debug information that you ship and one with that you archive. That will make it possible for you to analyze the core dump when/if the program crashes. You simply supply the unstripped executable to the debugger instead of the actually used (stripped) executable.

Another alternative if your build process is deterministic is just to archive the source code (by using a revision control system for example). Then you should be able to create the debug information by rebuilding (now with the -g flag). This is not a good idea though because there's lot of reasons that the build system wouldn't be deterministic - consider it more of a chance to be able to recover from the situation where you forgot the -g flag.